# Kendo grid expanding column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using kendo grid (which is awesome!) and one of my columns contains a description field. Does kendo come with support for expanding columns? i.e. if over a certain length display a '+' expand icon or will I need to use a third party library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to expand a record, you might use [`detailTemplate`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-detailTemplate) and maybe also [`detailInit`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-detailInit) event. Remember that detailTemplate might be either a string (KendoUI template) or a function. [This](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/detailtemplate.html) demo shows how to use it.
- If you want to expand a column, you should use a template in the column (see it [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.template)) definition and program there the logic needed.

Answer (score 1):

Grids do come with a resizing property. Not sure if this fits your needs though.

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/column-resizing.html

Comment: Hi, I have found that and it may be an option but a way to expand the content within the column would be great, thanks